# Regex to fetch all the field_names in ES queries

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch the all field_names of the elastic search query.

Example: `name:"Tom" AND city:("SanFransico" OR "Mexico") AND id:("123:34 X2")` should give me `name`, `city` and `id`.

I have tried out with `([^:\s]+):` regex which will give me all the matches and and for each match, 1st group will give me field_name.

But this regex is failing in some corner cases, where field_value contains column. As elastic search accepts columns (or any elastic search reserved words) in the field_values when they are surrounded by quotations or escaped with backslash ("`\`"), how can we write regex considering all the cases?

Below are the few cases that I observed which are failing with my regex `([^:\s]+):`

1. `name:"Tom" AND city:("SanFransico" OR "Mexico") AND id:("123:34 X2")` should give only name, city and id. But with my regex I am getting name, city, id, ("123.
2. `name:"Tom" AND city:("SanFransico" OR "Mexico") AND id:123\:34` is valid ES query and should give only name, city and id. But with my regex I am getting name, city, id, 123.

Comment: May you provide also an example for the problematic case?

Comment: I have added examples for the problematic cases. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIRD VERSION:**

Just a little tweak to handle braces around conditions.

`(\w+)\s*:\s*(("[^"]+")|(\([^)]+\))|[^\s]+)`

I have just changed the first part of the SECOND VERSION `([^\s:]+)` into `(\w+)`.

The pattern `[^\s:]+` matches EVERY character which is not a whitespace or a colon (including braces).

The pattern `\w+` only matches word characters, which should be suitable in most cases, except when your fieldname contains characters other then `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. But hopefully this will never be the case ;-)

[see example](https://regex101.com/r/vn5CtK/1)

---

**SECOND VERSION:**

A slightly better version might be the following but I am afrait that it is always possible to create a ES query which leads to false positives because the query could be arbitrarily complex. The best you can do is tweaking your regex until it fits your needs.

`([^\s:]+)\s*:\s*(("[^"]+")|(\([^)]+\))|[^\s]+)`

*Description:*

`([^\s:]+)` = fieldname

`\s*:\s*` = colon surrounded with optional whitespaces

`"[^"]+"` = field value surrounded by `"`

`\([^)]+\)` = field value surrounded by `()`

`[^\s]+` = literal field value

[see example](https://regex101.com/r/DiKsX7/1)

---

**FIRST VERSION:**

I have just added a `(^|\s)` in front of your regex: `(^|\s)([^:\s]+):`
This means the fieldname is at start of string (`^`) or (`|`) directly after a whitespace (`\s`). The name of the field is then in capture group 2.

[see example](https://regex101.com/r/deVAtu/1)

Comment: But this will fail for the case 
name:"Sai" AND city:("VIZAG" OR "DELHI") AND id:(" 123:34 X2") when there is space in the fieldvalue between " and first letter. In above example,  123: is also captured. But this query is a valid es query. Thank you

Comment: Hi Ogod, I need a help. Can you help me in modifying above regex so that it can work even when there is braces around queries.
Example: (name:"Sai" AND city:("VIZAG" OR "DELHI") AND id:(" 123:34 X2"))
(name:"Sai") AND (city:("VIZAG" OR "DELHI") AND id:(" 123:34 X2"))

Comment: @TomCruise I have added the THIRD VERSION to my answer.